# SonarQube Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have the below utility method and I am using multiple if statements and getting cognitive complexity issue. I went through some links, but I am not able to understand how should I change my code without affecting users of this method.

```
public static boolean isWrapperValid(WrapperClass wrapper, boolean isTechnicalToken){

    String key=null;
    boolean isValidWrapper = false;

    if (wrapper != null && wrapper.length() > 7
        && wrapper.substring(0, 6).equalsIgnoreCase("XYZ"))
    {
        wrapper= wrapper.substring(7, wrapper.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
    }
    if(wrapper != null && wrapper.equalsIgnoreCase("TFR")) {
        isValidWrapper=Boolean.TRUE;
    }
    try {
         key = wrapper.getKey();
    }
    catch (Exception exception) {
        return isValidWrapper;
    }

    if(key!=null) {

        Date tokenExpiryTime = key.getExpiresAt();

        if(tokenExpiryTime!=null) {
            return isValidWrapper;
        }

        String algorithm=key.getAlgorithm();
        if(!DESIRED_ALGO.equals(algorithm)) {
            return isValidWrapper;
        }

        String value6=key.getType();
        if(!DESIRED_TYPE.equals(value6)) {
            return isValidWrapper;
        }


        if(key.getValue1()!=null && key.getValue2().size()>0 && key.getValue3()!=null && key.getValue4()!=null && key.getValue5()!=null) {
            isValidWrapper=Boolean.TRUE;
        }
    }

    return isValidWrapper;
}
```

Please share your suggestions to refactor this code.

Comment: `(wrapper != null && wrapper.length() > 7
        && wrapper.substring(0, 6).equalsIgnoreCase("XYZ"))` == `false`. Unless "XYZ" is not actually "XYZ".

Comment: This will never be true `wrapper.substring(0, 6).equalsIgnoreCase("XYZ")`. Because you create a substring which will be six characters long (`wrapper.substring(0, 6)`). Therefore it can never be equal to `XYZ`.

Comment: @SubOptimal that's exactly what I was thinking when I wrote the comment above. Still, it might be possible, as we don't know exactly what `WrapperClass` is. It might be that `WrapperClass.substring()` doesn't do what we think it does!

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Good point. Did not thought about it.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException "XYZ " i had kept just not to show original values.. plz ignore those things

Answer (score 15):

I don't think that merging many `if` conditions to one or simply do a code clean up, for example by changing the order of some instructions, can solve your problem.

Your code does not match the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). You should refactor this big method to smaller parts. Due to this it will be testable, easier to maintain and read. I spent some time and did this:

```
public static boolean isWrapperValid(WrapperClass wrapper, boolean isTechnicalToken) {

    final WrapperClass unpackedWrapper = unpackWrapper(wrapper);
    boolean wrapperValid = isUnpackedWrapperValid(unpackedWrapper);

    Key key = null;
    try {
        key = unpackedWrapper.getKey();
    } catch (final Exception exception) {
        return wrapperValid;
    }

    if (key != null) {   
        if (doesKeyMeetsBasicConditions(key)) {
            return wrapperValid;
        }
        if (doesKeyMeetsValueConditions(key)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return wrapperValid;
}

protected static WrapperClass unpackWrapper(final WrapperClass wrapper) {      
    if (wrapper != null && wrapper.length() > 7 && wrapper.substring(0, 6).equalsIgnoreCase("XYZ")) {
        return wrapper.substring(7, wrapper.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    }
    return wrapper;
}

protected static boolean isUnpackedWrapperValid(final WrapperClass wrapper) {
   return wrapper != null && wrapper.equalsIgnoreCase("TFR");
}

protected static boolean doesKeyMeetsBasicConditions(final Key key) {
    Date tokenExpiryTime = key.getExpiresAt();
    if (tokenExpiryTime != null) {
        return true;
    }
    
    String algorithm = key.getAlgorithm();
    if (!DESIRED_ALGO.equals(algorithm)) {
        return true;
    }
    
    String value6 = key.getType();
    return !DESIRED_TYPE.equals(value6);
}

protected static boolean doesKeyMeetsValueConditions(final Key key) {
    return key.getValue1() != null && key.getValue2().size() > 0
           && key.getValue3() != null && key.getValue4() != null
           && key.getValue5() != null;
}
```

I don't know the domain logic, so some of my methods have stupid names etc. As you can see, now you have a lot of smaller methods with not many branches (`if` conditions) - easier to test (a static code is not nice, but you can mock it by using for example [PowerMock](http://www.powermock.org/)).

Comment: Good point about the single responsibility principle. But note it doesn't just apply to methods, but to classes too. It seems like `WrapperClass` is some kind of monstrous cross between a `String` and a `Map`. But then maybe the OP has no access to that class and can't change it.

Comment: Yes, I agree. My code is only an example for "how to start". It is hard to refactor something, when you don't know the domain and even the example code does not compile (it has been censored :P - `String` class does not have `getExpiresAt` method).

Comment: Good catch! Maybe the OP's `String` is not `java.lang.String` but his own class with an `import my.package.String;` statement.

Comment: @agabrys Thanks.. That was a really nice approach.. Once i get chance I will run sonar qube on this code and check if the issue is gone

Answer (score 1):

A bit of rewriting delivered a simplification, that still could be improved upon.

```
public static boolean isWrapperValid(WrapperClass wrapper, boolean isTechnicalToken){
    if (wrapper != null && wrapper.length() > 7
        && wrapper.substring(0, 6).equalsIgnoreCase("XYZ"))
    {
        wrapper = wrapper.substring(7, wrapper.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
    }
    boolean isValidWrapper = wrapper != null && wrapper.equalsIgnoreCase("TFR");

    try {
        String key = wrapper.getKey();
        if (key != null && key.getExpiresAt() == null
                && DESIRED_ALGO.equals(key.getAlgorithm())
                && DESIRED_TYPE.equals(key.getType())
                && key.getValue1() != null && !key.getValue2().isEmpty()
                && key.getValue3() != null && key.getValue4() != null
                && key.getValue5() != null) {
            isValidWrapper = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception) {
        // DO NOTHING
    }
    return isValidWrapper;
}
```

*After comment: here I catch any exception for all calls.*

Comment: It's not *entirely* equivalent (but probably ok as it is). The original will throw an exception if any of the methods called after `key = wrapper.getKey();` throw an exception. Your code will return normally.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException you are right; should have added a remark. There being almost only getters and the weird isValidWrapper usage led my attention astray.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Sonar should give you more flags: reusing the `wrapper` parameter is usually a bad practice, NPE where invoking `wrapper.getKey` because `wrapper` can be null, but anyway, not the point...

Try reducing the number of `if` statements by creating local boolean variables (or possibly 1 big `if` statement if you have less than 5 or 6 tests, but often less readable). Once it's done, you should only have 1 block testing these boolean variables, and have one return statement, like the example above (not necessarily accurate!):

```
boolean expired = tokenExpiryTime != null;
boolean desiredAlgo = DESIRED_ALGO.equals(key.getAlgorithm());
boolean desiredType = DESIRED_TYPE.equals(value6);
if (expired || !desiredAlgo || !desiredType) {
    return isValidWrapper;
}
```

However, your Cognitive complexity level seems pretty low if this kind of algorithm triggers it...

Another big way to reduce an algorithm complexity is to turn sub-blocks of code (loops, if and try-catch) into private methods. In your example, it could be something like a `checkWrapperValidity` method, responsible for every test returning `isValidWrapper`

Answer (score 0):

Please add below line on the top of your specific file in react,

> /* eslint-disable sonarjs/cognitive-complexity */

*i have developed react app using eslint, so according to your build platform you can change